# How do you make a specific folder that has subfolders to be uneditable in Sublime Text

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3

How do you make a specific folder that has subfolders to be uneditable in Sublime text? ? I know it's possible but how ? Like i have some old projects that I want to use as a reference to study my old code, but i"m worried that I mistakenly edited some parts of that specific module / file, when I'm mindlessly touring around my code.. How do I do it ? like making a specific folder to be uneditable in sublime text that only modifying it can change it . I mean I tried installing this one package : https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Toggle%20Read-Only

But it still gives me a prompt whenever I want to changed something from a file

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to make sure that your source code is covered by some sort of Source Control, such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/); this is just always a good idea in general and unrelated to your particular question. Having your code under source control means that when you edit a file (accidentally or on purpose) you can see exactly what you edited or throw those edits away and go back to what you had if you want to.  If you also push your code to an external server, such as [GitHUb](https://github.com/) (if you use `git`) then you also have a cheap and easy off-site backup of your code as well.

That said, if you want to make files uneditable, that's more the job of your file system than the tools that you're using to edit the files (in this case Sublime Text).

All file systems and operating systems should have the concept of a `read-only` file, which sounds like what you want. A file being marked as read-only stops you from accidentally modifying it; depending on the software that you use, edits are either impossible or will need to be confirmed.

In your case, you can do this in a couple of different ways. If you only want to protect a couple of files, then you would do a <kbd>Right click</kbd> and choose `Properties`; in the bottom of the `General` tab there is a check box you can check to make that file read-only:

[image: Single File]

If you have many files, you can do the same thing by editing the properties of the folder that contains the code instead:

[image: Whole Folder]

When you do this to a folder, the property set works a little differently; since you're modifying the folder as a whole, you need to click the box twice to change it from a square (shown above) to a check mark. When you apply the change, you will be asked if you only want to make files inside of that directory read-only, or all files in that folder as well as all folders under it; choose as appropriate.

Sublime will let you open `read-only` files and  will also let you modify their contents, but when you try to save you will get a warning dialog telling you that the file is `write-protected`; you need to confirm if you want to actually save changes or not; (other software may not prompt with such a dialog and may just fail):

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

If you choose to save, you will remove the `read-only` attribute and make the file normal again.

If you want to make a file completely un-editable so that you can't even accidentally change the file, you can achieve that with a simple plugin in combination with making the file `read-only` (see [this video](https://youtu.be/lBgDilqulxg) if you're not sure how to apply a plugin):

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import os


class ReadOnlyListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if (os.path.exists(view.file_name())
                and not os.access(view.file_name(), os.W_OK)):
            view.set_read_only(True)
```

---

**EDIT:** The internal `View Package Files` command will open package resources from `sublime-package` files transparently and give them a filename that represents where they would exist on disk if they were not in the package file.

The plugin from the original answer would stop you from being able to use this command by noting that the file is not writable (because it does not exist on disk) and make the `view` read-only, which stops the file content from being displayed because the `view` can't be modified.

This is rectified in the edit above by only taking action if the file actually exists on disk (the `View Package File` command already makes files it loads in this manner `read-only` if they do not exist on disk).

---

This makes an event listener that checks every time you open a file to see if the file is writable, and if it's not it makes the view `read-only`. This distinction is Sublime specific; regardless of the underlying state of the file, you just can't make any changes to such a file at all. That doesn't stop you from saving the file even if you haven't made any changes, which would have the same effect as the above.